# Extract string from img src attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could i take fontsize, fonttext and fonttype value from following img src

```
<img 
  src="bin/contenthandler.php?fontsize=36&fonttext=apple&fonttype=fonts/FOO.ttf"
  class="selected content resizable">
```

I think it can be done with regular expressions but I am bad with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing it with the location object would be ideal, avoids all the troublesome regex.
Borrowed from:
[Parse URL with jquery/ javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript)
and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location

```
function buildValue(sValue) {  
    if (/^\s*$/.test(sValue)) { return(null); }  
    if (/^(true|false)$/i.test(sValue)) { return(sValue.toLowerCase() === "true"); }  
    if (isFinite(sValue)) { return(parseFloat(sValue)); }  
    if (isFinite(Date.parse(sValue))) { return(new Date(sValue)); }  
    return(sValue);  
}      
function getVars(url) {
    var oGetVars = {};  
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    var iCouple, aCouples = a.search.substr(1).split("&");  
    for (var iCouplId = 0; iCouplId < aCouples.length; iCouplId++) {  
        iCouple = aCouples[iCouplId].split("=");  
        oGetVars[unescape(iCouple[0])] = iCouple.length > 1 ?     buildValue(unescape(iCouple[1])) : null;  
    }  
    return oGetVars;
}

console.log(getVars('http://google.com?q=123&y=xyz'));
```

This will return an object with all the variables of the query.
[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Toukakoukan/sFYbj/)

Comment: by far the best answer, and reusable :)

Answer (score 2):

Despite the other two answers, here is an alternative,

```
$('img[src]').each(function (i,n){
   var item  = $(n).attr('src');
   var query = item.split('?');
   var items = query.split('&') ;
   // so now you get the point, u split each item again by the "=" sign :) this is reusable     
   // provided you put it on a function, and it can search to return a specific one, with a little imagination :) 
});
```

Another alternative is by using the URI library.

I have used this numerous times and you get exactly what you want, and get everything to do with URI/URL manipulations.

http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/

```
$('img[src]').each(function (i,n){
   var src  = $(n).attr('src');
   var get_query = URI(src).query()
   console.log(get_query)
});
```

here are some examples...

```
URI("testme?test").query();// returns: test
URI("testme?a=1&b=2").query(true) // returns: {a: "1", b: "2"}
URI("testme?font_size=15&font_name=arial").query(true).font_size // 15
```

more information about how to use ... click here http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#accessors-search

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the value `36`.

```
var rx = /fontsize=(.*?)&/;
var fontsize = rx.exec('<img src="bin/contenthandler.php?fontsize=36&fonttext=apple&fonttype=fonts/FOO.ttf" class="selected content resizable">')[1];
```