# Parse a url with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, url

I have a URL like this one:

`/events/3*1*1*0*0*3*3*1/permalink/391013797602909/`

or this one:

`/*o*i*z*r*g/posts/3804270420760`

I have censored the event ID and the user ID. Basically I want to get the Event ID and the permalink ID (long number), and the user ID and post ID. I am confused with how to do that with Javascript/jQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript

Comment: RGB, that is NOT a duplicate, and guess what, I already saw this exact question. I am trying to parse the URL, and not just get a `GET` variable. Next time, you should read the question before voting down or writing wrong/not useful comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use .split("/"); on the url in question. That returns an array of strings split by the slash.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed format, you can use RegExp to match the patterns you want:

```
'/events/3*1*1*0*0*3*3*1/permalink/391013797602909/'
    .match(new RegExp('/events/([0-9*]+)/permalink/([0-9]+)'))
```

Returns array of 3 elements, 2nd item is event, 3rd item is permalink

```
'/*o*i*z*r*g/posts/3804270420760'
    .match(new RegExp('/([0-9a-z*]+)/posts/([0-9]+)'))
```

Returns array of 3 elements, 2nd item is user id, 3rd item is post id

Assuming the `*` won't be there, so you can drop it from the character ranges :)