# jQuery: How to remove query string from a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

How can I remove a query string from the url of a link? For example I have

```
<a href="http://example.com/somepath/anotherpath?title=dog">The Link</a>
```

How can I remove just the `?title=dog` from the url using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can remove the query string from a link by simply changing the [`search` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#Properties) of the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) object.

```
$("#your_link")[0].search = "";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uSrmg/1/

Or if you need to target multiple elements:

```
$("a.someclass").each(function() {
 this.search = "";   
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uSrmg/4/

---

If you wish to parse an arbitrary URL to remove the query string, you can inverse the trick explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript/6644749#6644749). For example:

```
function remove_qs(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a'); // dummy element
    a.href = url;   // set full url
    a.search = "";  // blank out query string
    return a.href;
}
```

This should be quite robust as it uses the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) object to do all the parsing.

Example usage: http://jsfiddle.net/uSrmg/

---

Comment: Ok this looks really close, but how can I get it to work if the url has a path in it like in my updated example?

Comment: Oops.. yeah it is. Now my issue is that I have a bunch of links on my page that I need to remove the query string from. The code in your first example is only working on the first link.

Comment: There ya go! That will do it :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

To remove the querystring from an anchor tag:

```
var anchor = $('#yourAnchor');
var href = anchor.attr('href');

if (href.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
   anchor.attr('href', href.split('?')[0]);
}
```

Comment: Checking that the `href` attribute contains a `?` character is unnecessary - `.split()` will simply return an array with a single element (the entire string) if the separator isn't present.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist until another developer decides to copypasta this code and use it elsewhere, introducing a bug. if anything, there should be a comment about this behavior instead of an if statement.

Comment: If they do that's **their** problem, and in my opinion a very poor reason for including unnecessary checks in your code.

Answer (score 3):

There is one more way to replace search with blank.

```
String(document.location.href).replace("&title=dog", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var url=$('a').attr('href').split('?')[0];
```

Split on the "?" and get the first item. If you want to change the url of all links on the page then you can use this code:

```
$('a').each(function(i,el){ 
    $(el).attr('href', $(el).attr('href').split('?')[0]);
});
```

Comment: this will give you the base URL, not the querystring - you meant `[1]`, but you probably want to add some bullet-proofing in case the `href` has no `?` character.

Comment: @jbabey They want to remove the querystring, so returning the base URL is correct.

Comment: Sorry, there will be a path in the url too. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Hmmm I'm getting this error for some reason.. 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined 
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)

Comment: There is no indexOf in my code, did you mean to respond to jbabey's answer? My function works: http://jsfiddle.net/2jqWA/

Answer (score 0):

You can split the query string from the url on page load as:-

```
$(function(){
  if(Modernizr.history)
  {
    history.replaceState({},"",location.href.split("?")[0]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
var url = "www.foo.com/test?name=kevin&gender=Male&id=1234";

var res = url.replace("&gender=Male", "");

window.location.href =res;
```

Split particular string query parameter in url by javascript