# How to get the last two characters of url with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a url with the following format:

```
base/list.html?12
```

and I want to create a variable which will be equal to the digits after the question mark in the url of the page. Something like:

```
var xxx = anything after the ? ;
```

Then I need to load dynamic data into that page using this function:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf(xxx) >= 0){ 
alert('Data loaded!');
}
```

How can I achieve this? and are the codes above correct?

Thanks

Comment: This is JavaScript - you dont require a library to read the url ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = document.location.href.split('?')[1];
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `split` to get the characters after ? in the url

```
var xxx = 'base/list.html?12';
var res = xxx.split('?')[1];
```

or for current page url

```
var res = document.location.href.split('?')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [6644654](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript).

```
function parseUrl( url ) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a;
}

var search = parseUrl('base/list.html?12').search;
var searchText = search.substr( 1 ); // removes the leading '?'
```

Answer (score -1):

`document.location.search.substr(1)` would also work