# Regular Expression for matching keywords in different styles of URL's

Tags: .net, regex, url, regular-language

```
http://mywebsite/index.aspx?db=DAYTON#id%3D7304%3Bpage%3D1%3Bview%3Dpages

http://mywebsite/#id%3D3D7304%3Bpage%3D1%3Bview%3Dpages
```

The two URL's above go to the exact same place but are of different styles. I am trying to write out a one line expression that will create a match no matter which style of URL is thrown at it. I have been focusing primarily on everything after the "mywebsite/"

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: What is the language? Please tag the language or tool when you are asking regex question!

Comment: Seeing as those fragments will never arrive at a webserver, it's a pretty safe bet the language is `javascript`.

Comment: Do you want a regex that just matches those two URLs or others as well?

Comment: If you are indeed looking for a javascript solution, then you may want to check out this q/a: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6644654/211627

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  What language are you using? You probably don't want to use a regex, but rather an existing module that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

If you're using PHP, you want the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


If you're using Perl, you want the [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module.



If you're using Ruby, use the [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module.

Comment: I do apologize for not tagging the programming language being used. I was not sure if it mattered or not since I thought that the Regular Expression language was universal. I am using .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a *heavy* One-Liner Regex:

`^http:\/\/mywebsite\/(index\.aspx\?db=[A-Z]+)?#((id%\w+(%3B)?)|(view%\w+(%3B)?)|(page%\w+(%3B)?))*$`

It will accept your website with an optional `index.aspx?db=` (set to some UPPERCASE value) and any order of the 3 variables you use: `id`, `view` and `page`.

Colorful explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/jB2jS3

Answer (score 0):

First of all, decode the URLs to make things easier:

```
http://mywebsite/index.aspx?db=DAYTON#id=7304;page=1;view=pages
http://mywebsite/#id=3D7304;page=1;view=pages
```

Now you can write two regular expressions to match each `path` and combine them with `|` operator([Demo](http://regexr.com?340u1)):

```
http://mywebsite/(index.aspx\?db=(\w+)#id=(\d+);page=(\d+);view=(\w+)|#id=3D7304;page=1;view=pages)
```

you can also use [named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) if your programming language supports them.

---

Note that the regular expression above won't match the URLs if arguments order changes.

I suggest you to use a URL parser if you can.

Comment: If the web standard says the parameters can be in any order (which it does), then it would be a bad idea to code your website in such a way that a valid query breaks it.