# Passing a var to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to pass the `totalScore` `var` to another page `onclick` so that it can be displayed there? ex: click submit link it goes to yourscore.html and display the score on page

```
$("#process").click(function() {   
    var totalScore = 0;
    $(".targetKeep").each( function(i, tK) {
       if (typeof($(tK).raty('score')) != "undefined") {
          totalScore += $(tK).raty('score');
       }
    });
    alert("Total Score = "+totalScore);
});
```

Comment: You would need to add it as a query string parameter, or possibly a cookie.

Comment: javascript tag but you have posted jQuery

Comment: which variable you want to access in this page yourscore.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let we suppose that your HTML may be as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#process").click(function() {   
        var totalScore = 0;
        /*
         Your code to calculate Total Score
         Remove the next line in real code.
        */
        totalScore = 55; //Remove this

    alert("Total Score = "+totalScore);
      $("#submit-link").attr('href',"http://example.com/yourscore.html?totalScore="+totalScore);  
});


    });
  </script>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
  <button id="process">Process</button>
<br />
<a href="#" id="submit-link">Submit Total Score</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Check out this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EMoqOjA/1/edit)

In yourscore.html you may able to know more in the following queation to extract the URL parameter from the URL:

[Parse URL with jquery/ javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is generally done by changing the url of the page. i.e. if you are going go to a new page, just do:

```
http://example.com/new/page?param1=test
```

If the page already exists in a new window (like a popup that you own), set the url to something new:

```
http://example.com/new/page#param
```

Open a window:

```
 var win = window.open('http://example.com/new/page?totalscore'+totalscore,'window');
```

Change the location:

```
 win.location.href='http://example.com/new/page?totalscore'+totalscore;
```

Other ways of doing this could be [websockets](http://www.websocket.org/) or cookies or localstorage in HTML5.

Comment: how would I pass the `totalscore` var down to a link is it something like http://example.com/new/score.html?totalscore also how would grab totalscore on the new page?

Comment: @acctman You can find how to handle querystring in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: @Jason but the score it held inside the `totalscore` var. totalscore=1000 would work for manually setting a score right?

Comment: window.location = "domain.com/path/to/page?totalscore="+totalscore;

Comment: i commented out the alert and added 
`win.location.href='LP3.html?totalscore'+totalscore;` but when i click my link `<a id='gogo' href='#'>FINISH</a>` nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

if you are aiming to support more modern browsers the elegant solution could be to use sessionStorage or localStorage! Its extremely simple and can be cleared and set as you need it. The maximum size at the low end is 2mb but if your only storing INTs then you should be okay.

DOCS:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage
http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/

DEMO:
http://html5demos.com/storage

EXAMPLE:

```
addEvent(document.querySelector('#local'), 'keyup', function () {
  localStorage.setItem('value', this.value);
  localStorage.setItem('timestamp', (new Date()).getTime());
  //GO TO YOUR NEXT PAGEHERE
});
```

Comment: i like this because the passed info will not appear in any coffee shop's http log like a GET param would...