# Bootstrap active menu highlight breaks when using pagination

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, highlighting

So I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 to build my front-end, in this case simple tabbed menu. I was struggling a lot to make it work, because menu links didn't want to highlight properly when you click on them. By that I mean, if you for example click on the page about.php that link should be marked as active and therefore have some CSS styling applied on it. I saw many posts here on stackowerflow but they only partially worked for me. For example some jQuery code that people posted would do proper highlighting but would prevent links from working.

Finally I have found a solution that is working great except when I use pagination. Let me explain:

Here is the bootstrap html code of my menu:

```
    <nav class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li><a href="index.php"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php"> About Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php"> Contact Us </a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php"> Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.php"> Portfolio </a></li>
    </ul>
<nav>
```

In order to make menu highlighting working I am using this javaScrpt code:

```
var url = window.location;
// Will only work if string in href matches with location
$('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

// Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
$('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
```

So when I start the app index.php is marked as active and that is great, if I click on about.php I will go to that page and it is also marked as active, that is great too. But since I have pagination on index.php, and I click on Pagination link 2 url will change to: index.php?page=2, and highlighting will break, index.php will not be marked as active anymore.

Do anyone know what is going on here, and what can we do to fix this ? I'm not that good with JS.

Comment: this may help you to parse the url properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript

Comment: I got no idea how that can help me...O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just using `window.location` for your url, try using:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
```

If your current url is `www.mywebsite.com/index.php?page=2` the above should output `/index.php`.

You can use `url.replace('/', '')` to get rid of that first slash.

EDIT:

Since your pathname may have multiple parts, such as `/something/index.php` we need to deal with that. Another way of doing it is:

```
var urlpath = window.location.pathname;
```

In your code you have:

```
$('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

You can change the selector to:

```
$('ul.nav a[href="' + urlpath.split('/').pop() + '"]').parent().//...etc
```

This is doing the splitting and isolating the `index.php` portion in one go. `index.php` will of course be `contact.php` or `whatever.php` on other pages.

Try this JSFiddle I just created, showing the above line in action: http://jsfiddle.net/N9SHq/

Comment: First: pathname returns: www.mywebsite.com/index.php. Second why should I remove / ? It is ?page=2 that is causing problems I guess. I need to build urls dynamically somehow, to remove anything that comes after ? and return that for further processing.

Comment: What does `alert(window.location.pathname);` give you on your page? Works as described for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: You remove the '/' because `/index.php` does not match what you have in your href attribute. You have `href="index.php"` with no slashes.

You are comparing the url in your href with the current url. Since the query string is causing an issue, using `window.location.pathname` retrieves just that part of the url, which matches what is in your href.

Comment: alert(window.location.pathname); gives me : /mysite/index.php. Firefox 27.0

Comment: Ah yes. Pathname returns everything after the domain name (and before the query string/hashes etc). I will update my answer.

Comment: This works OMG. Thank you so much, I wish I can buy a bear or something ! Thanks thanks thanks ! :D