# Parsing date parameters with JavaScript without using a third-party library?

Tags: javascript, parsing

If I have a URL like this:
`http://localhost/my/service/endpoint?from=2015-01-28T05:55:00.000-06:00&to=2015-01-28T07:55:00.000-06:00`

I want to be able to parse the `from` and `to` get parameters into JavaScript variables but the URL could potentially have additional parameters before or after what's shown above.  What's the best way to parse these without using a third-party library?

I'm interested in being able to parse the full date for `from`and `to` and nothing but these dates regardless of the number of GET params in the URL.

Comment: [dublicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: You can parse it using stirng operations: `indexOf` and `substring` are your friends.

Comment: window.location.search gets your query string, then its just a matter of splitting or regex match to get what you want