# Clean URL by removing one paramater and its value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following URL addresses:

```
www.mydomain.com/default.aspx?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
OR
www.mydomain.com/default.aspx?param2=value2&param1=value1
OR
www.mydomain.com/default.aspx?param3=value3&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

How can I remove only the part "param1=value1" from those URL addresses with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse URL with jquery/ javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644654/parse-url-with-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
function RemoveParam(url, p) {
   return url
  .replace(new RegExp('[?&]' + p + '=[^&#]*(#.*)?$'), '$1')
  .replace(new RegExp('([?&])' + p + '=[^&]*&'), '$1');
}

var url='www.mydomain.com/default.aspx?param3=value3&param1=value1&param2=value2'

 alert(RemoveParam(url,'param1'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8dXvt/456/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var url = "www.mydomain.com/default.aspx?param3=value3&param1=value1&param2=value2" 
url = url.replace("&param1=value1", "");
```

Comment: I think she wanted to define the parameter name only and don't care about the value. And your solution doesn't work for the first parameter (?param1...) either.