# Selecting links with jquery

Tags: jquery

Please help, I need to select the "10" on this link using jquery where it says `id=10` and also the "do" where it says `type=do`

```
<a class="myClass" href="/local/web/do.php?type=d0&id=10">link</a>
```

I tried jQuery`(this).attr('href');` but that returns all the link address,
I need to set each as a variable.

I want something like 
var id = "the selector that selects only the id value"
var type = "the selector that selects only the type value"

Thanks

Comment: What link? Can you show an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: <a class="myClass" href="/local/web/do.php?type=d0&id=10">Link</a>

Comment: @Kingsley check my answer

Comment: i guess this will help https://github.com/kevincox/url.js source https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753120/7887883

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript may help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you want to get the value of id, type on click of the link? Or do you want to get the ID on page load? Are there multiple such links with same class ".myClass" on the page? Can you post code snippet of what have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, I have a loop that displays multiple posts with different ids and types, so I just want to get the id of the link and type when clicked so I could send as variable to another page using jquery ajax function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getQueryVariable(query, variable) {
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
}

$(".myClass").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var query = href.split('?');
    var vars = query[1];

    console.log(getQueryVariable(vars, 'type'));
    console.log(getQueryVariable(vars, 'id'));
});
```

Try this, reference: [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Is that what you are looking for??

I've splited id from clicked link

```js
function doalert(obj) {
  var type = obj.getAttribute("href").split('type=')[1];

  console.log("id--", obj.getAttribute("href").split('id=')[1], "type--", type.split("&")[0]);
}
```

```html
<a class="myClass" href="/local/web/do.php?type=d0&id=10" onclick="doalert(this)">link</a>
```

Comment: I believe this would just get the `id` parameter, but he asked to extract both `id` and `type`