# How I can write a function that will display the path in the Browser Console

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to write a function that will display the path in the Browser Console when I click on a link of the menu on the sub-category, the menu looks like this (https://www.sephora.fr/) in this e-commerce website

For example : Parfum => ForMen => Cologne

How to get the path when I click on Cologne

Thanks

Comment: Like, breadcrumbs in the console log?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get pathname values from url in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966711/how-can-i-get-pathname-values-from-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this will return the relative path for the website whenever an anchor tag is clicked on.

```
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

anchors.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(event.target.getAttribute("href"));
}));
```

Also check out [JavaScript click event listener on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655189/javascript-click-event-listener-on-class) for a similar question.

Comment: Side note: this is not a persistent solution, since one you leave the page you click on, you would have to execute this code in the browser console again.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to get the path without the domain name, you can use this:

```
function getUrlWithoutDomain() {
   return window.location.pathname;
}
```

If the domain name is also important, this will get you the full url:

```
function getFullUrl() {
   return window.location.href;
}
```